# how to solve failed to launch the browser process on whatsapp-web.js

Tags: php

I'm using centos 8 and nodejs 16,I installed nodejs version 16,When I want to run an example like the code below,I get an error:

WHATSAPP WEBJS: [Github Whatsapp webjs](https://github.com/pedroslopez/whatsapp-web.js/)

in app.js

```
   const { Client } = require('whatsapp-web.js');
    
    const client = new Client();

client.on('qr', (qr) => {
    // Generate and scan this code with your phone
    console.log('QR RECEIVED', qr);
});

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Client is ready!');
});

client.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.body == '!ping') {
        msg.reply('pong');
    }
});

client.initialize();
```

[image]

Comment: Why is this tagged with PHP? Please only add tags that are relevant to the issue/question.

Comment: you need to install chromium

Comment: installing chromium doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

I think your OS is missing low-level librarie expected to be installed which is `libnss3.so`

Try to install it :

```
sudo yum update
sudo yum -y install nss
```

This should get `libnss3.so` to be installed and present on your machine.